# What equation would give me a graph like this?

Tags: calculus

Is there some equation that will give me a line/curve that will pass through two points (say, the origin and (1,1)), and allow me to adjust the bend of the curve between these two points, by manipulating some variable in that equation?

Here's an image to show what I mean:
[(Photo showing hand-drawn graph)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFLim.jpg)

Sorry if this is a poorly asked question - I'm not too sure how else to ask.

Thanks

Comment: You want the points to be independent from the second variable? That is, you want it to always pass through the origin and $(1,1)$?

Comment: The simpler can be $y=x^a$ with $0<a<1$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/321157/856

Answer (score 2):

A simple function is 
$$\frac{(1+c)x}{1+cx}$$
I think, $c>-1$.

Comment: You should graph your function. You curve does not go through $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Also you should specify the $c$-value.

Comment: You should stick to the second equation

Comment: @Arbuja, thanks, I think I have it now.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest graph appears to be linear and suggests using $f(x)=x$. The top most graph closely resembles $\sqrt{x}$, and so $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ should fit the bill. Then we can use $h(x)=x^{\alpha}: 1/2\le\alpha\le1$.

(Note that any power $\alpha\in (0,1]$ should work.)

Answer (score 0):

I think your curvature resembles that of superellipse-like curves. I think you might like.

$$y=\left(-(-x+1)^{{((2n+1)}/{(2k+1))}}+1\right)^{({(2k+1)}/{(2n+1)})}$$

Where $n$  and $k$ are integers. You want $k$ to be large odd integer, say $100$. While $k$ is ***fixed*** you want ***adjust*** $n$ to be between $2k+1<2n+1<\infty$. For reference when $2n+1=k$ we have a straight line and when $2n+1>k$ than the curve starts going outward.

Its a long equation but I think it is much more accurate according to your picture.